# why my emulator is not starting?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to start android emulator but it is not starting whatever I do.

this is my config :
[image]

and this is what it is been always 
[image]
the screen is lock here and it does not change or open

Comment: you might be allocating too much RAM for it

Comment: it was joke...  lol.. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decreasing the RAM down to about 512MB. And then wait. The android emulator can be really slow on some machines.

The [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator can be a bit faster. You might want to check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't allocate too much RAM for the emulator, it can be ridiculously slow, taking up to 5 or 10 minutes to start up if your machine is slow (like mine).